# Rotating an ImageVIew should be CLICKED in its rotated position in android below HoneyComb versions

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-imageview

I am trying rotate an ImageView along with its original location (rotating the image aswell as the view). So that After rotation, when I click on the rotated Image in its current position, it should be able clicked in the rotated location only.

For this solution I am trying the following code. However it is rotating is going fine. After the rotation end I need to place the ImageView and Image in the rotated Location to make it able click over there only. But it is not going successfully. I am unable to rotated Image location axis points to place correctly. Can any one please suggest a way to resolve this issue.

fyi-It should work on Gingerbread version android-9

```
 aniView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("", "Clicked on IMAGE VIEW - 1");
            }
        });

        RotateAnimation rotate5 = new RotateAnimation(0, 150,
                Animation.INFINITE, 100, Animation.INFINITE, 250);
        //rotate5.setFillAfter(true);
        rotate5.setDuration(2000);
        rotate5.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        aniView1.setAnimation(rotate5);

        rotate5.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                int newTop = (int) (aniView1.getTop() + aniView1.getWidth());

                aniView1.layout(aniView1.getLeft()-200, newTop,
                        aniView1.getRight(),
                        aniView1.getBottom() + aniView1.getMeasuredWidth());

                // aniView1.setLayoutParams(new
                // RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It had worked for me. Animated state will be persisted from that

Edited:

Ok, and I am able to do that with this code in my app:

```
Animation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF);
        rotateAnim.setDuration(5000);
        rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
        rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        rotateAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        rotateAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
        rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: no boss, my rotated Image also should be clicked, It means the complete image as well as view should completely from original position to rotated position

Comment: Please check edited answer, I was able to click on rotated image in that position only. Hope it works in your case, too

Comment: please change the rotation degrees other than 360 and try ? In your case in the above code you are rotating to same location. please try other cases 30 60 90 120 degrees below 360 and try and let me know

Comment: Yes, I just checked.. doesn't work with any other degree. Will check tomorrow if I could find any other way for that

Answer (score 0):

Put this file under android res --> anim --> loading_rotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1200" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
```

and in your activity

```
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.loading_rotation));
```

and where you want to stop just call

```
view.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: I have commented in the first answer, AS MY ROTATED IMAGE SHOULD BE ABLE TO CLICKED, AFTER ITS ROTATION PLEASE READ QUESTION COMPLETELY, I tried all these things these will just rotate image not the complete view from its original position.

Comment: this code is just for rotation, rotated image not able to be clicked in its rotated position

Comment: For any click event you can set listener and surely you will able to click before/after or while rotating and call a Listener from a widget/view.